# How to set up custom image for front camera in android emulator?

Tags: android, camera, emulation

I know that there is a way to up custom image into 3d virtualscene. However virtualscene doesn't work for front camera, only for back camera. Is there a way to set up custom image for front camera?

When I try to use virtualscene for front camera:

```
emulator -camera-front virtualscene
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR   | Invalid value for -camera-front <mode> parameter: virtualscene
Valid values are: 'emulated', 'webcam<N>', or 'none'
```

Where 'webcam' is hardware webcam and 'emulated' is nonsense pixelated image:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir01b.png)
Maybe there is a way to replace this pixelated image with a custom one? Or is there a way to make virtualscene work for front camera?